# How do I measure shortest distance where it crosses +/- 180 (the International Date line)

Tags: qgis, distance-matrix, shortest-path

I'm trying to measure the shortest distance between two sets of points on the globe in QGIS.  One set of points is close to -180 and the other close to +180,  QGIS Distance matrix is giving me a measurement of approx 31,000 KM so is obviously measuring the long way around.  I want the short way around measurement that crosses the international date line.

Any suggestions?  I've seen some people suggest re-projecting the map so that it splits at the prime meridian. However, I have a script that automates this calculation across several thousand data-sets, so I ideally want to solve this in a way where I don't have to re-project.  I currently use WGS 84 / EPSG:4326 and on the fly transformations enabled.

Comment: Algorithms are at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points-haversine-formula . You can implement one in your script.